# Facebook access token expiration

Tags: facebook

I am a little confused about calculating the time until the access token expires.

I am using server authentication (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/).

When I get the authentication code from the Facebook's request to my redirect URL, I send an authentication request back to Facebook and I get the access token along with 'expires' parameters, lately I could see that the expires is a long value that represents the time in seconds until the token expires. For some reason I think it used to be time in miliseconds.

Can I assume that the expiration time is now + expires (in seconds) - it seems to me too long (about ~5109691 seconds) - does it make sense?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Access token is supposed to be active for about half an hour. And for all operations temporary tokens are enough. What actually you want to do using FB API?

Answer (score 10):

Server authenticated access tokens are valid for two months. 
The value you are receiving is correct.

Edit:
https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Read the 'Server-side OAuth Developers' section.

Comment: @JessicaCowen please accept answer if you think it is correct.